# Joint limiting distribution

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two sequences of random variables of mean zero and unit variance such that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the following properties hold:

- $X_n$ has limiting Gaussian law: $X_n\rightarrow N(0,1)$,
- $Y_n$ has limiting Gaussian law $Y_n\rightarrow N(0,1)$,
- The covariance of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ vanishes: $\text{Cov}(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow 0$.

Is it true that the limiting distribution of $(X_n,Y_n)$ is two-dimensional standard normal $N(0,I_2)$? Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: You would need $(X_n, Y_n)$ to be **jointly** Gaussian.

Comment: @Raoul: Thanks, but that is too strong, because the main goal is to show the limit normal law. Do you know any weaker and nontrivial condition?

Comment: There is really nothing else that you can say without making assumptions on the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

No construct a trivial sequence with $X_{n}=X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_n=SX\sim N(0,1)$ where $S=1$ with probability $1/2$ and $S=-1$ with probability $1/2$ and $S$ is indpendent of $X$. Then it is easy to see that $SX$ is uncorrelated with $X$ but $X$ and $SX$ are not jointly normally distributed since $X+SX=0$ with probability 1/2

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. It seems like the uncorrelatedness is too weak for the joint limit law. The independence between $X_n$ and $Y_n$ is certainly sufficient but it may be too strong for my case. Do you know any weaker sufficient condition?